# Using jQuery Mobile to display 2 buttons side-by-side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to the whole jQuery/Mobile/HTML5/CSS3.

Using the code below, I want to display the buttons horizontally (50% wide each) and stretch across 100% of the screen. Sounds simple, but for some reason the buttons display vertically:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #page-buttons .ui-controlgroup-controls { width: 100%; }
        #page-buttons .ui-controlgroup-controls a { width: 50%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page-buttons" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <a href="#" data-role="button">Previous</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button">Next</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The only way to display the buttons side-by-side is to set the width to 49.8%. But why?

I have created a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/j0q0gqca/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have border on `button`'s so you should add `box-sizing: border-box` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/j0q0gqca/2/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#page-buttons .ui-controlgroup-controls {
  width: 100%;
}
#page-buttons .ui-controlgroup-controls a {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: When you put this into your site, I would be careful with the wildcard, maybe apply the box-sizing just to the element that requires it to save yourself from any issues down the line.

Comment: You can use more specific selector like `#page-buttons *` or `#page-buttons a` https://jsfiddle.net/j0q0gqca/6/

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to solve this is by giving your container a `display: flex;`

```
#page-buttons .ui-controlgroup-controls {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Hunter377/j0q0gqca/1/)

Comment: Thanks, that works, but the answer from Nenad Vracar would be better and less code wouldn't it (referring to the wildcard)?

Comment: I doubt very much that the amount of code in the css here is going to make any difference. What you should be looking at is the method used to achieve the result. This solution uses 'flex' which has more browser issues than the 'box-sizing' solution (I'm not saying it is wrong). The 'box-sizing' solution by Nenand, imo, gets to the root of the problem, which is the 'width: 50%' is all well and good but you need to account for the padding and border on the button to display them side by side. Which is exactly what 'box-sizing: border-box' does